# Парсинг html кода после js используя selenium и python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Пытаюсь выполнить некоторые действия на сайте используя Selenium(ff) + Python.
В Момент, когда я делаю ввод в поле своих данных:

```
elem_from = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="from"]')
elem_from.send_keys(city)
```

происходит подгрузка дополнительных элементов js, список из предложенных вариантов, вот этот список мне необходимо спарсить.
Я сделал скриншот страницы и там это список есть, но

```
driver.page_source
```

выдает html код до обработки события js
как получить полный код html?

Comment: Адресочек сайта не подскажете?

Comment: loads.ati.su, город о правления и город назначения